# SQLite very slow SELECT time

Tags: select, sqlite, inner-join

I got some strange behavior of my program, and maybe you can bring some light into it.

Today i started testing some code, and realized, that a specific query was really slow (took about 2 minutes).

here the select:

```
select distinct table1.someName
from table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.t2_id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.t1_id
INNER JOIN table4 ON Table3.id = table4.t3_id 
INNER JOIN table5 ON table5.id = table4.t5_id 
INNER JOIN table6 ON table4.id = table6.t4_id 
where t4_name = 'whatever'
and t2_name = 'moarWhatever'

and timestamp_till is null 

order by someName
```

So the thing is, the result is about 120 records. the `INNER JOIN`s reduce the amount of checks for `timestamp_till is null` to about 20 records on each record.

What bugs me most is, i've tested to insert the whole table `table6` into a new created table and renamed `timestamp_till` to `ende`. On that table the select is done in about 0.1 seconds ...

Is timestamp_till some sort of reserved name of SQLite3? Could this be a bug in the SQLite engine? Is it my fault? oO

edit: add the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output...

When querying with the `and timestamp_till is null` he gives:

```
0|0|4|SEARCH TABLE table5 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_table5 (t4_name=?) (~1 rows)
0|1|3|SEARCH TABLE table4 USING INDEX table4.fk_table4_1_idx (t5_id=?) (~10 rows)
0|2|2|SEARCH TABLE table3 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|3|0|SEARCH TABLE table1 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1rows)
0|4|1|SEARCH TABLE table2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|5|5|SEARCH TABLE table6 USING INDEX table6.fk_table6_ts_till (timestamp_till=?) (~2 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

and the fast one is:

```
   select distinct table1.someName
    from table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.t2_id
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.t1_id
    INNER JOIN table4 ON Table3.id = table4.t3_id 
    INNER JOIN table5 ON table5.id = table4.t5_id 
    INNER JOIN table6 ON table4.id = table6.t4_id 
    where t4_name = 'whatever'
    and t2_name = 'moarWhatever'    
    order by someName
```

and its result:

```
0|0|4|SEARCH TABLE table5 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_table5_1 (t4name=?) (~1 rows)
0|1|3|SEARCH TABLE table4 USING INDEX table4.fk_table4_1_idx (t5_id=?) (~10 rows)
0|2|2|SEARCH TABLE table3 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|3|0|SEARCH TABLE table1 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1rows)
0|4|1|SEARCH TABLE table2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|5|5|SEARCH TABLE table6 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_table6_1 (id=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

with the test-table that is a copy of `table6`

```
0|0|4|SEARCH TABLE table5 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_table5_1 (name=?) (~1 rows)
0|1|3|SEARCH TABLE table4 USING INDEX table4.fk_t5_idx (t5_id=?) (~10 rows)
0|2|2|SEARCH TABLE table3 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|3|0|SEARCH TABLE table1 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1rows)
0|4|1|SEARCH TABLE table2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0|5|5|SEARCH TABLE test USING INDEX test.fk_test__idx (id=?) (~2 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

---

create script for `test`

```
CREATE TABLE "test"(
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "t12_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "value" DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  "anfang" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "ende" INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY("id","t12_id","anfang"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_test_t12_id"
    FOREIGN KEY("t12_id")
    REFERENCES "table12"("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_test_id"
    FOREIGN KEY("id")
    REFERENCES "id_col"("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_test_anfang"
    FOREIGN KEY("anfang")
    REFERENCES "ts_col"("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_test_ende"
    FOREIGN KEY("ende")
    REFERENCES "ts_col"("id")
);
CREATE INDEX "test.fk_test_idx_t12_id" ON "test"("t12_id");
CREATE INDEX "test.fk_test_idx_id" ON "test"("id");
CREATE INDEX "test.fk_test_anfang" ON "test"("anfang");
CREATE INDEX "test.fk_test_ende" ON "test"("ende");
```

soo long zai

Comment: What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for both queries?

Comment: Joining 2 tables will take some time, depending on how many entries they both have, not so much on the final result. Joining 6 tables will take even more time. Make sure all foreign keys are indexed, that should help.

Comment: @CL. added to the question
@MPelletier yes i know, but the same query with the `timestamp_till is null` needs 1-2 minutes and without not even a second ...

Comment: Could you elaborate which table `timestamp_till` and `someName` are in?

Comment: added the fast query and where `timesamp_till` is from.

Answer (score 2):

A first note: SQLite will use only 1 index in its query. Never more (with the current version).

Thus, here is what SQLite is doing:

- Slow query: use the index on `timestamp_till`
- Fast query (no timestamp_till): use the (auto) index on `table6.id`.

I see two workarounds.

You could use a subquery:

```
select distinct SomeName FROM
(
   select table1.someName as "SomeName", timestamp_till
   from table1
   INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.t2_id
   INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.t1_id
   INNER JOIN table4 ON Table3.id = table4.t3_id 
   INNER JOIN table5 ON table5.id = table4.t5_id 
   INNER JOIN table6 ON table4.id = table6.t4_id 
   where t4_name = 'whatever'
   and t2_name = 'moarWhatever'
) Q
where timestamp_till is null 
order by SomeName;
```

Or you can drop your index on `timestamp_till`, if you don't need it elsewhere.

There is also perhaps some speed gains to be made by reordering your joins. Usually the smallest table first is faster, but this can vary greatly.

Comment: cool that looks promising, but how would it explain, that the 'slow query' on a 1:1 copy with other name for `timestamp_till` can be super fast and on the original table not?

Comment: @Zaiborg Was your other name also indexed?

Comment: yeah i created the whole test from a renamed create script

Comment: @Zaiborg I'm starting to doubt the "1 index" rule. I don't see your query where `timestamp_till` has another name.

Comment: the query is the same, i just copied the table and renamed `timestamp_till` into `ende` to be shure it cant be a name conflict ... today the 'slow query' was on the first attempt like the 'fast one' (instant result) and after some runs slow as usual ...

Comment: @Zailborg `Do you have the "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` for the query with `ende`?

Comment: added the query plan for the testtable

Comment: @Zaiborg This is getting hard to follow. Can you write the create query for your test table? Also, your `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3` don't appear to have primary keys.

Comment: they have a primary key, that is a reference to a table that 'collects' them. that counts for most tables in the database.

i will try to get the create script asap

Comment: I'm assuming your query with `test` doesn't have `ende` in the where clause, or does it?

Comment: yes that query includes the `ende is null` in the where clause

Comment: There's still a difference somewhere that I'm not seeing. It can't be just the names.

Comment: i simply used 'find and replace' to rename it from `table6` into `test`so i have no clue what can be the problem.